# ng-repeat throwing invalid Expression

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm a total angular noob and trying to create a simple test app where. I'd like to read out some userdata in a partial. The user data is in my event controller. I assign the event controller to a form in my new.html partial after navigating to #/new via a route controller.

The error I get when trying to loop through the users in my partial is "Error: ngRepeat:iexp Invalid Expression". I can't figure out how to ng-repeat through those users.

Any thoughts?

**My index.html:**

```
    <div class="container"  style="width: 500px; margin: 0 auto;">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills" ng-controller="NavigationController as navigationCtrl">
            <li ng-class="{active: navigationCtrl.isActive(1)}">
                <a href="#/">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li ng-class="{active: navigationCtrl.isActive(2)}">
                <a href="#/new">Nieuw</a>
            </li>
            <li ng-class="{active: navigationCtrl.isActive(3)}">
                <a href="#/another">Nog een</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <div ng-view></div>
    </div>
```

**My new.html partial**

```
<form action="" ng-controller="EventController as event">
    <div ng-repeat="users as user">
        <label>Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" ng-model="user.name">
        <br>
        <label>Emailaddress</label>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" ng-model="user.email">

        <br>
        <input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" ng-click="event.addEvent($event)" value="Klik">
    </div>
</form>
```

**And last: My angular code**

```
(function () {
    var app = angular.module('testApp', ['ngRoute']);

    app.controller('NavigationController', ['$scope', '$route', function ($scope, $route) {
        $scope.$route = $route;
        this.activeTab = 1;

        this.setActiveTab = function (tab) {
            this.activeTab = tab;
        };

        this.isActive = function (tab) {
            if ($route.current && $route.current.activeTab) {
                return $route.current.activeTab === tab;
            }

            return false;
        };
    }]);

    app.controller('EventController', ['$scope', '$controller', function ($scope, $controller) {
        this.users = [
            {name: 'aa'},
            {name: 'bb'}
        ];

        this.addEvent = function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            console.log(this);
        };

    }]);


    app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
        when('/new', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/new.html',
            controller: 'NavigationController',
            activeTab: 2
        }).
        when('/another', {
            templateUrl: 'partials/another.html',
            controller: 'NavigationController',
            activeTab: 3
        }).
        otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/',
            controller: 'NavigationController',
            activeTab: 1
        });
    }]);
})();
```

I've tried changing this for $scope to no avail.

Comment: -1 for not taking a look at the [error message](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/ngRepeat/iexp?p0=users%20as%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%201,#)

Comment: plus 1 for asking a question and providing proper code sample.

Comment: Well yeah, an invalid expression can be ANYTHING if you don't know what to look for :-p It was just a dumb over-looked typo/syntaxing error; We've all had those more than we're willing to admit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You write `ng-repeat` in wrong way in your `new.html` partial page

it should be like

**new.html**

```
<div ng-repeat="user in users">
```

Comment: That was just plain dumb. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, diff syntex of `ng-option` and `ng-repeat` create confusion.

Answer (score 1):

you have not written **`ng-repeat`** in right way change it to:

```
 <div ng-repeat="user in users">
```

Answer (score 1):

Correct syntax for ng-repeat is

```
<element ng-repeat="item in [1,2,3]">
```

Also you can use things like `track by $index` if you have duplicated values in your collection like [1,1,1].

Ref. https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

Answer (score 1):

There are few issues in your code. Please change all **this** references to **$scope** and then quickly fix below html code:

```
<div ng-repeat="user in users">
```

It should work but update me otherwise also.

[Working demo for your reference (route codes excluded for demo purpose only)](https://jsfiddle.net/jcex6j0y/2/)

thanks,
Ashok